# Processing specific files in a directory in python

Tags: python, json

I wrote a small python program which processes all the files in a directory. I want to restrict that to include only JSON files in that directory. For example, the line `fname in fileList:` in the code snipped below should only enumerate files with the extension *.json

```
#Set the directory you want to start from
rootDir = '/home/jas_parts'
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootDir):
    print('Found directory: %s' % dirName)
    for fname in fileList:
        print('\t%s' % fname)
        fname='jas_parts/'+fname
        with open(fname, 'r+') as f:
            json_data = json.load(f)
            event = json_data['Total']
            print(event)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since your file name is string you can use the [**`str.endswith`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) method to check if it is `json` file.

```
if fname.endswith('.json'):
    #do_something()
```

Answer (score 3):

Just filter the names that you are interested in.

```
if fname[-5:] == '.json':
```

(of course, you can also use `os.path.splitext`, or `re`, doesn't really matter how you get to the extension)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a general solution to the question: "How do I do X to all files with names matching some pattern under directory Y?"

```
#!python
from __future__ import print_function
import fnmatch, os, os.path

def files_under(directory, pattern):
    '''Yield all files matching pattern under some directory
    '''
    for p, dnames, fnames in os.walk(directory):
        for match in fnmatch.filter(fnames, pattern):
            yield(os.path.join(p, match))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if len(sys.argv) < 3:
        print('Must supply path and (quoted) pattern', file=sys.stderr)
        sys.exit(1)

    try:
        for each in files_under(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]):
            print(each)
    except EnvironmentError, e:
        print ('Error trying to walk tree: %s ' % e, file=sys.stderr)
        sys.exit(2)
```

The function is `files_under()` and the rest is just a very simplistic wrapper around it to print the matching results.

It's also easy to extend this to handle multiple patterns and even, with a little extra work, to ensure that files with names matching multiple patterns are only `yield`ed once each.  But I'll leave these enhancements as an exercise to the student.

Comment: Incidentally a usage pattern for this function:  `json_files = files_under('.', '*.json')` ... then later you can use: `for each in json_files: ...` (for example).  That way the code and read almost like English.